# Data binding suddenly giving weird errors while building on 2 way data binding on editText

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have this line `android:text="@={loginVM.email}"` in my layout file.

Everything was working fine a while back but now it is giving error while building the project. I works fine if I remove the = sign and write only `android:text="@{loginVM.email}"`

> Error:(15, 57) error: package
>   does not exist
>   Error:(17, 54) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerLoginComponent
>   Error:(27, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ActivityLoginBinding
>   Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found
>   data binding errors. Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data
>   binding errors.

I have already tried cleaning the project and also the option to restart and invalidate cache options.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after updating my android studio and Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

just clean our project and try to rebuild some times data binding is taking files from your cache so clean project and try to rebuild.